# Curly braces as comment delimiters

Tags: listings

In the language I am defining in `listings`, text put inside `{*` and `*}` is commented out. I tried to implement this as `morecomment = [s]{{*}{*}}`, but understandably LaTeX gets the nesting confused. The result is that text placed between two `*` is commented out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{*` must be written as `\{*`, the same holds for `*}`: `*\}`.

The same `escaping` mechanism must be used for `#`, `%` and `\` itself, i.e. `\#`, `\%` and `\\`. (This is actually stated multiple times in the `listings.pdf` manual)

I've 'misused' the `Gnuplot` language to define as additional comments `{*...*}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=Gnuplot,morecomment = [s]{\{*}{*\}},commentstyle={\bfseries \color{blue}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  # A gnuplot comment
  plot sin(x) lt 2
  {* *}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]